# Android asks me which app to use every time, even after I've set my app as the default. Why?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

My app has an activity for opening YouTube links, with intent filters which I've copied from [NewPipe](https://newpipe.net/). It works fine: when I click on a YouTube link, Android asks me which app to use, and my application appears in the list. **The problem is, it asks me this every time, even after I go to the settings and select "Open in this app".**

NewPipe works as expected: after choosing "Open in this app", it's used to open YouTube links every time, without asking.

Here's the AndroidManifest portion for my activity, copied from [here](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/blob/dev/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml):

```xml
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Youtube filter, copied from NewPipe -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="youtube.com" />
                <data android:host="m.youtube.com" />
                <data android:host="www.youtube.com" />
                <data android:host="music.youtube.com" />
                <!-- video prefix -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/v/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/embed/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/watch" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/attribution_link" />
                <!-- channel prefix -->
                <data android:pathPrefix="/channel/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/user/" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/c/" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="youtu.be" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any tests to conclusively answer this, but I think in my case this was because my app didn't have a "main activity". I've added a proper activity with categories LAUNCHER and DEFAULT and now the app behaves as I expect.

This could be a security feature, to prevent "hidden" apps from hijacking somebody's intents.